# how use LIKE keyword in primary key of mysql using ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

how to use LIKE keyword in primary key of mysql using ubuntu?.

I tried,  create table abc ( regno bigint(12) primary key like'123');
but this query what i need is, it need to check while inserting values.

Comment: The ubuntu flag isn't needed, this is the same regardless of OS I think.
It is not clear what you are asking, LIKE keyword isn't used in the table declaration in the way you use it.

Can you describe in your question what you are trying to achieve? What do you expect to do with the table, what do you expect to happen when you insert or select?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'CHECK' constraint to check the value before it gets inserted in the table.